# What is the tactic that does nothing?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Sometimes it is useful to have a tactic which does nothing. I've tried to search "empty tactic" or "null tactic" but these do not give me the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tactic you are looking for is `idtac`, short for "identity tactic"

```
 Tactic idtac (ident ​| string​ | natural)*
```

> Leaves the proof unchanged and prints the given tokens. Strings and naturals are printed literally. If ident is an Ltac variable, its contents are printed; if not, it is an error. [source](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.idtac)

You can give `idtac` arguments, which are useful for debugging.